# How to run third party JS script in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have some third party JS scripts in angular app which has $(document).ready functions, At start everything works fine but when I change the routes via routerLink then some functionality does not work but when page is reloaded then it works.

I have tried importing JS files in angular.json and index.html.

Please help if you have any solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: You shouldn't use $(document).ready in your library but, in another way, in your app made in Angular -> Angular use its virtual DOM, putting some code between the real DOM and the Angular's one could cause a lot of errors, maybe this is your case. You shoul put your logic executed into the `$(document).ready` into some `angular life-cycle`.

Comment: I have some custom JS file which uses document.ready function is there any change I can do in custom js file ?

Comment: can you edit the third party js script?

Comment: What changes do I need to make

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the page is fully loaded once and then only portions of the page are re-loaded when you navigate on your routes (SPA). So, the `$(document).ready` event is fired only once, when the page is loaded.

An workaround to achieve this is fire your third party script on your own in some angular life-cycle, for example, angular router `NavigationEnd` event:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
     // do your stuff here
  }
});
```

But this is bad, it's easy to lost control. This could be better if you encapsulate the third party library in some Angular component, e.g. a directive, to avoid `$(document).ready` pattern.